# Place two images, in grid layout, under a glass pane?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I hope you are having a great day. I have a basic java question involving glass panes. I have two images, in grid layout, and I am trying to keep them, and their **separate** layout manager **under** the glass pane, and keep a JLabel (Which is meant to follow the mouse) **over** the glass pane. I have tried this multiple times, but each time **all** the components get under the glass pane. Here is my code:

```
package Buttons;


import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Giraffewindow extends JDialog {
public Giraffewindow() {
    JDialog giraffewindow = new JDialog();

    Icon giraffe = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("giraffe.png"));
    Icon windows = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("windows.png"));

    giraffewindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    giraffewindow.add(new JLabel(windows));
    giraffewindow.add(new JLabel(giraffe));


    giraffewindow.pack();
    giraffewindow.setTitle("GIRAFFE!");
    giraffewindow.setVisible(true);
    giraffewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel glass = ((JPanel) giraffewindow.getGlassPane());
    glass.setVisible(true);
    status = new JLabel("I can change");

    giraffewindow.add(status);
    giraffemousehandler giraffemouse = new giraffemousehandler();
    giraffewindow.addMouseListener(giraffemouse);
    giraffewindow.addMouseMotionListener(giraffemouse); 
    setLayout(null);
}


JLabel status = null;

class giraffemousehandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener { //MouseAdapter makes it so that you don't have to have all 7 implemented mouse listener methods

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        status.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, 60); //Makes JLabel follow mouse

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        status.setText("Entered");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        status.setText("exited");

    }

}
}
```

Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: `setLayout(null);` is a problem.  `extends JDialog` is confusion matters and adds no value

Comment: Even without setLayout(null);, I get the same issue. Without extends JDialog, I cannot make my JDialog properly, nor can I have this line of code:   giraffewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a series of issues, most just cause confusion, but...

```
 giraffewindow.add(status);
```

Basically, you're adding the `status` label to the `JDialog` and not the glasspane...

I'd avoid having `extends JDialog`, when you simply create another dialog, this is going to seriously confuse the issues even further.

Another problem is you add the mouse listener to the dialog, which is okay, but I assume you want to know when the mouse moves beyond the scope of one or more of the images, this means you need to add the mouse listener to the labels as well.

Because of the way that the `GridLayout` works, you will never actually "exit" one of the components, for very long ;)

Because the `MouseEvent`s will now be generated within the context of the labels, you will now need to convert the `Point` of the event back to the glass pane's context

Comment: YAY, thank you so much, I should have added it straight to the glass pane!  I did this:

Comment: giraffewindow.add(status);

Comment: and it worked! Thankyou, I have marked you as best answer and liked!